# Como controlar mensalidades e acesso a aplicação?

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema que deve bloquear o acesso de quem não efetuar o pagamento do boleto da mensalidade.

Dei uma olhada no projeto [BoletoPHP](http://boletophp.com.br/) para geração de boletos e me atende parcialmente. Consigo gerar os boletos, mas não sei quando e se foram pagos.

O que preciso é de um feedback em nível de sistema sobre o pagamento do boleto, algo como a API do PagSeguro faz, para que o bloqueio da conta seja automático.

Por ora não posso usar APIs como PagSeguro, MercadoPago etc.

Comment: poderia ser um pouco mais específico? além disso mostre um pouco da parte relevante/problemática do seu código para podermos ajudar

Comment: Não existe código que consiga esse tipo de informação sem acessar *alguma* API, seja dos intermediários que você citou, ou diretamente com a instituição financeira responsável pelo boleto.

Comment: O banco que gera o boleto não tem fornece um arquivo dos pagamentos realizados ou algo parecido?

Comment: Esse tipo de informação vai ser específico para cada instituição bancária. Você precisa consultar a instituição com que você trabalha e verificar **se** e **como** eles disponibilizam esse tipo de serviço.

Comment: @perdeu  procurando como fazer só li exemplos de boletos sem registro e, nesse caso, o banco só toma conhecimento do boleto quando ele é pago e a forma de verificar o pagamento é manual.

Comment: @bfavaretto  e utluiz tenho que ver como cada banco trata isso para fazer as devidas integrações com os boletos registrados, correto? Se for isso, tiraram minha dúvida.

Comment: Vou deixar esta pro @utluiz confirmar, tenho pouca experiência prática com bancos. Mas acredito que você precise somente lidar com o banco emissor do boleto.

Comment: Ao menos no Brasil, os bancos informam sobre pagamentos realizados com remessas de arquivos. Existem diversos padrões de arquivo, sendo que todos os bancos são obrigados a usar o padrão da FEBRABAN (CNAB, com quantidades de colunas fixas). Se alguém quiser elaborar sobre isso em uma resposta, sintam-se a vontade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Controle de pagamentos via boleto

1. Gerar o boleto de cobrança
2. Gravar dados da cobrança em banco de dados (assinante, **vencimento**, valor, *etc*)
3. Obter o arquivo-retorno do banco (todo dia útil)
4. Processar o arquivo-retorno (aqui você fica sabendo os detalhes dos pagamentos)
5. Atualizar o banco de dados com as informações obtidas (marcar cobranças pagas, *etc*)
6. Verificar os pagamentos em atraso (ainda não pago após data de vencimento) e efetuar o bloqueio

#### Gerando o boleto

Sempre do lado do cliente, estive envolvido com geração de boletos usando PHP desde 2007, tendo utilizado os serviços do Banco do Brasil, Bradesco e Caixa Econômica Federal, nas modalidades sem registro e registrada.

No ano passado, fiz um [Bundle de geração de boletos para o Symfony 2](https://github.com/paggybrasil/PaggyBoletoBundle) que faz o mesmo serviço que o BoletoPHP: a partir dos dados de cobrança informados, gera o boleto correspondente. Porém, esta é só uma parte do sistema.

As informações que seguem são válidas para os bancos mencionados acima, dentro da experiência que tive. Creio que os demais sigam o mesmo modelo.

#### Obtendo o arquivo-retorno

Para controlar as mensalidades, ou seja, saber quais boletos foram pagos, você precisa obter o **arquivo-retorno** que é gerado todo dia útil pelo banco, e contém as informações sobre os boletos processados naquele dia.

Como você obtém o **arquivo-retorno** do banco?

Ou através de *Internet Banking*, ou de algum *software* proprietário a ser instalado por um técnico do banco. Infelizmente, não há uma API ou outra maneira mais simples e passível de ser automatizada por parte do cliente. A rotina de obter o arquivo-retorno do banco, e em seguida enviar o mesmo para o seu sistema processá-lo, é uma tarefa manual.

A resposta exata sobre a forma de obtenção desses arquivos será dada pelo próprio banco, seja quando for feita a contratação da carteira de cobrança, ou em qualquer outro momento.

#### Gerando e enviando o arquivo-remessa

Nos contratos de carteira registrada, é necessário também gerar e enviar para o banco o chamado **arquivo-remessa**, para que os boletos gerados pelo seu sistema sejam registrados no sistema do banco. Os envios são feitos de maneira similar (*Internet Banking* ou *software* proprietário). Na Caixa Econômica  há um processo de *homologação* para **validar** a formatação dos seus arquivos-remessa. Depois de uma fase de testes, é ativada a fase de "produção", quando os arquivos-remessa enviados passam a ser efetivamente registrados.

Também no ano passado, no mesmo sistema em Symfony 2, implementei uma classe para gerar arquivos-remessa a partir dos dados de cobrança e dos boletos gerados pelo sistema - porém esse código não está em domínio público.

#### Padrão CNAB

Tanto os arquivos enviados para o banco (**arquivo-remessa**, apenas para a carteira registrada) quanto os arquivos recebidos do banco (**arquivo-retorno** diário) seguem uma formatação padrão.

O padrão CNAB (Centro Nacional de Automação Bancária) tem algumas variações - CNAB 240, CNAB 400, *etc*. Nos *sites* do Banco do Brasil e da Caixa Econômica Federal estão disponibilizados os documentos técnicos que detalham o padrão utilizado para essa comunicação entre o banco e o cliente.

- [Banco do Brasil - CNAB240](http://www.bb.com.br/portalbb/page44,3766,2163,0,0,1,2.bb)
- [Caixa Econômica Federal - DOWNLOADS](http://www1.caixa.gov.br/download/asp/download.asp?subCategId=198&CategId=65&subCateglayout=Manuais&Categlayout=Cobran%E7a%20Caixa%20%96%20SICOB)

Cada banco deve manter uma documentação semelhante, a qual é necessária para implementar qualquer solução que precise gerar ou processar arquivos "retorno" e/ou "remessa".

#### Processando o arquivo-retorno

Como existem variações entre cada banco, não existe uma solução pronta para todos. É preciso estar com a documentação técnica, e fazer a implementação de acordo. Assim como temos "vários tipos de boletos" no BoletoPHP... temos vários "tipos de arquivo-retorno" e vários "tipos de arquivo-remessa".

Eu já fiz implementações de processamento de arquivo-retorno, em PHP, para os três bancos mencionados, dos quais os meus clientes eram clientes. Esta é outra parte do sistema cujo código não está em domínio público.

Não é difícil, mas é trabalhoso - há muitos detalhes, muitos campos... não é nada agradável.

#### Em suma

O que você vai precisar é:

1. **Diálogo** com o banco a fim de obter acesso aos arquivos-retorno
2. **Rotina** de obter o arquivo e enviar para o seu sistema
3. **Implementação** de *script* que processe os arquivos-retorno recebidos pelo sistema

Answer (score 2):

Eu sempre trabalhei em empresas do segmento financeiro, que prestam serviços e desenvolvem sistemas para bancos. Porém, não tenho muita experiência com os sistemas de boletagem pois não trabalhei diretamente com eles.

Entretanto, já tendo trabalhado em sistemas *cliente*, isto é, que geram os boletos e recebem o retorno, posso dizer que as instituições financeiras utilizam padrões para envio e recebimento de informações sobre boletos. O mais comum onde trabalhei é o CNAB.

Mas o seu problema não é o formato em si, mas como a instituição vai (ou não) disponibilizar essa informação para seus clientes através de um *web service*.

Veja bem, os sistemas com que trabalho são executados internamente no banco, então nós lemos o Retorno do CNAB através de uma *procedure*, uma tabela ou um arquivo TXT num diretório configurado pelo banco.

Mas, para disponibilizar essa informação para **terceiros**, cada banco vai criar uma solução própria, a exemplo dos *internet bankings* que existem por aí.

Minha sugestão é que você vá até a agência para falar com seu gerente e questione sobre esse serviço. Provavelmente ele vai encaminhar essa dúvida para alguém de TI do banco, que poderá informar o formato dos dados e o modo que é disponibilizado.

**Talvez** esse serviço seja oneroso, já que o banco precisa se preocupar com segurança, disponibilidade e não quer qualquer um acessando serviços diretamente.

Algo que eu vejo em muitas lojas virtuais menores é uma funcionalidade onde o próprio usuário faz o controle dos boletos pagos, já que ele pode acessar o *internet banking* da empresa. Alguns bancos (Banco do Brasil, por exemplo) possuem exportações dos dados de extrato do *internet banking* em formatos CSV e XLS, então seria possível facilitar um pouco e permitir que o usuário faça upload desses arquivos para seu sistema e ele identifique se há boletos pagos no extrato.

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer esse controle é necessário que você faça a consulta do status dos boletos (se foi pago ou não, com atraso, etc...) no sistema do banco, essa  consulta é feita via troca de arquivos de texto com o banco através do padrão CNAB, porém cada banco tem suas próprias extensões para o padrão CNAB o que acaba obrigando você a ter um modelo diferente de envio e recepção para cada banco. A especificação desses modelos pode ser achada na internet ou no site de cada banco.

É importante notar que cada vez que você faz uma consulta o banco te cobra uma taxa, por isso limite a quantidade de consultas.